# Avoid printing character vbFormFeed as up arrow

Tags: vb.net, printing

I have a program in visual basic that prints some large reports, sometimes with hundreds of pages. There is a lot of encapsulation here, but it boils down to us using the PrintDocument.Print() command to print the document. When it prints, it prints the form feed characters as up arrows (in windows 10). Is there anyway to get these to print as blanks, and just have them start a new page?

Let me know if you need anymore details. This is my first Visual Basic experience and I'm not sure what info would be useful.

Comment: [Miscellaneous constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/miscellaneous-constants): `vbFormFeed chr(12) Not useful in Microsoft Windows or on the Macintosh`.

Comment: What do you mean not useful? Is there another way to ensure page breaks?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I don't know if anyone else will encounter this, but I fixed it, so maybe my method will help you. There is a PrintPage event handler that fires off when you are printing, and basically it's just a matter of reading a string up to the form feed character, substringing that off to another string and then printing that other string, then culling it from the original string. Making sure you remove the vbFormFeed character from each page.